# Magnitude of a photon?

Tags: photons, terminology

I encountered the following sentence in my textbook, which I don't quite understand,  and after an unfruitful google search, I still can't figure out what they mean by **magnitude** in this context:

> ..."split a photon into N components with magnitude ϵ"?

Comment: sounds wrong in my opinion. Missprint or something. A photon is one of the elementary particles, cannot be split, it has mass 0 and is only characterized by its energy/frequency and spin orientation (=/-1). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon

Comment: @annav would the sentence "split photons into N components with magnitude $\epsilon$ where the magnitude refers to components and not photons?

Comment: It does not make sense at all. One can split classical electromagnetic waves, not individual photons. There is nothing there to split. what is the book?

Comment: Maybe they mean that they send the photon on a beam splitter (or a set of them) so that, technically, the photon is "split" into all the output modes. The formulation is not ideal but that might also depend on the context in which the whole formulation is used.

Comment: @OndřejČernotík a photon is an individual particle withe energy hnu and a spin (+/-1). It cannot be split. It can Compton scatter on an electron and change its frequency, be absorbed kicking an electron to a higher level, or pair produce in the field of a nucleus for high energy gammas. thats about all.

Comment: @Bart More context would be helpful.  What's the textbook and page number (in case anyone has it)?  Are you analyzing the photon as a quantum field?  I agree with the others that this doesn't really make sense, but maybe we can re-interpret what's being said.

Comment: @annav I know that. What I mean is that they probably mean splitting its probability amplitude among several modes. It's not the same thing and the term "splitting a photon" is definitely not a suitable one, but this is where I think the core of the statement might be.

Comment: @OndřejČernotík I'm pretty certain you are right. At least that's how I'd interpret it anyway.

Comment: Well you can, loosely speaking, "split a photon wavefunction into two components" using a half silvered mirror.  Maybe this is the sort of thing they're talking about.

Comment: @twistor59  That is the probability for the photon to go through or be reflected. The individual photon is not split of course. It certainly is very sloppy terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Thats nonsense. In *Spontaneous parametric down-conversion*, one photon may produce two photons with half the energy. No one refers to them as components. The term "magnitude" is unusual in the context of photons. Photons have energy and spin.